# What are the advantages, if any, to using mako's or pylon's form handlers instead of coding the form manually?

Tags: python, pylons, mako

Trying to decide if I should be using mako to handle the forms in my application or not.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: what mako form handlers are you referring to ?   these? http://techspot.zzzeek.org/?p=28

Comment: Please explain how you think you'd use mako (a template tool) or pylons (a web framework) to "handle" forms?  The two tools you've named aren't even the same kind of software.

Comment: @S.Lott I think he means using Pylons' built-in form helpers. It seems he is just new to the framework.

Comment: Hi -- Yes sorry I am new to the framework.  I meant Pylon's WebHelpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll save you a lot of time (even if you use them just during development) to use Pylons built-in form handling. Later if you want to strip them out and hard code a full form for each page, you can but I'd use the built-in one and find ways to customize within it before going completely manual about it.